# Unix: Delete File code giving some process

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, unix, solaris

I have coded java code to delete the file from the particular path. We are able to see the process running using the below command and we find only one entry.

```
root@ad4d # ps -ef | grep Del

root 27896 27895   0   Jun 24 pts/5       0:49 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/dist/DelFile.jar
```

But when the Administrator checks the process which is running from the command below we can see many child threads and parent thread process below

```
 root@almt4d # ps -aAdeflcjLPyZ | grep Del

 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891     1   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891     2   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891     3   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891     4   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891     5   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891     6   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891     7   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891     8   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891     9   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    10   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    11   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    12   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    13   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    14   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    15   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    16   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    17   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    18   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    19   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    20   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    21   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    22   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    23   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    24   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    25   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    26   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    27   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    28   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    29   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    30   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    31   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    32   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    33   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    34   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    35   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    36   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    37   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    38   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    39   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    40   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    41   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    42   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    43   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    44   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    45   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    46   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    47   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    48   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    49   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    50   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    51   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    52   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    53   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    54   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    55   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    56   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    57   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    58   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    59   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    60   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    61   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    62   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    63   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    64   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    65   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    66   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    67   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    68   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    69   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    70   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    71   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    72   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    73   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    74   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    75   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    76   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    77   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    78   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    79   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    80   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    81   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    82   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    83   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    84   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    85   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    86   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    87   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    88   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:04 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    89   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    90   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    91   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    92   -    96   TS  58 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    93   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    94   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    95   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:45 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
 S   global    root 27896 27895 26891 26891    96   -    96   TS  59 37144 116392        ?   Jun 24 pts/5       0:00 java -jar /oracle/php/online/jars/d
```

Can anyone please explain from where these kind of child and parent thread process started executing. 
I have executed only one DelFile.java which has only one thread
 Is there anyway to control the child threads which are visible to the Administrator using below command

```
root@almt4d # ps -aAdeflcjLPyZ | grep Del
```

DelFile.java

```
package DelFile;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;
import org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout;
public class DelFile extends Thread{
     static Logger log =Logger.getLogger(DelFile.class);
     FileAppender app = null;
     public DelFile()throws IOException{
         app = new FileAppender(new SimpleLayout(), "/oracle/php/online/jars/dist/del_file.log");

     }
     public void logSet(){
        app.setLayout(new PatternLayout(("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  %-5.5p  [%t] %m%n")));
        log.addAppender(app);

    }
     boolean flage=true;
public void run(){

    while(flage){
         final String str="xls";
         String add="/oracle/php/online/jars/dist/";

         String[] paths;
         File f = null;

         try{     
         f = new File(add);
         paths=f.list();
         for(String path:paths)
         {  

            String temp="";
            String temp1="";
            int count=0;

                for(int i=path.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
                     if(path.charAt(i)!='.'){
                        count++;
                         temp+=path.charAt(i);//pmbs                                             
                    }else{ 
                    for(int j=temp.length()-1;j>=0;j--){
                        temp1+=temp.charAt(j);
                        }
                        if(str.length()==count){
                        break;
                        }
                     }
                }
                if(str.equals(temp1)){
                        long time= new File(add+path).lastModified();
                        long utime=time+600000l;
                        while(utime>System.currentTimeMillis()){
                           Thread.sleep(601000);
                        }
                           logSet();
                           log.info(path +"  :  File is deleted");
                           new File(add+path).delete();
                }                 
         }
        }catch(NullPointerException np){

            try{
                Thread.sleep(600000);
            }catch(InterruptedException ip) {}           

        }catch(InterruptedException ie){
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
           DelFile r=new DelFile();
           r.start();  
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean flage=true;
public void run(){
    while(flage){
         // flage not referenced below, no break, no return
         ...
    }
```

This is called an endless loop. It causes the thread to run for ever, which explains the many entries seen by ps.

**Later**

The LWPs (or threads) you see are JVM internal threads - not threads created by your program. I thought you were worried why they'd remain in the machine, apparently for ever, which is indeed due to the endless loop: the program doesn't terminate even after all files are gone.

Comment: Wrong, an infinite loop in a single thread of a single process as no reason by itsel to create many threads.

Comment: @SergeBallesta See my clarification.